# Maven repository setup for different environment

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am setting up an internal maven repo feed for our team. I dont know how to deal with different environments.

I want to have 3 different feeds e.g. dev, ppe and prod. How can I parameterized my pom.xml so that the build/install command can talk to either of these three feeds based on some parameter?

for example

mvn clean deploy -dev : will install and deploy to dev feed

mvn clean deploy - ppe : will install and deploy to ppe feed

Can it be done by profiles? if yes, how?
or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what and why you need distinct repos so we can help you ?

Comment: basically I am going to incorporate the mvn deploy command into builds. now I don't want some one to do a dev branch build and it deploys something in a feed which is used by PROD. That's why I am thinking of 3 separate feeds.  There might be other better design where dev, ppe and prod don't step on each other but I don't know that, if you know, please let me know. I am super new to all these

Comment: Maybe git could help you with branches but i’m not sure i understood well your question. By the way as you said on your question take a look at the profiles. You can basically write 3 different poms in one in a way.

Comment: I think you misinterpreting maven function here. No need to have different repository for each branch.  One of maven advantages is having central local repository for all artifacts (even for different projects). Each branch is build by its own pom (so you can handle differences between them by it and other pom conventions). Source control will do the rest.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "feed"? A Maven repository?

Comment: @JF Meier. yes. feed is maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be closed as too broad, but ...

If you have three stages for new software and the artifacts should move to the next stage when tests are successful, you usually *don't* build the artifact again, but move or tag it somehow to distinguish stages. The reason for this is simple: When you rebuild an artifact, you end up with a slightly different artifact than the one you tested before. So strictly speaking, you need to repeat the tests.

Practically, sometimes people *do* rebuild the artifact for some reason or the other, but you should have such a good reason to do it.

Furthermore, there is often a "stage before the first stage" where you build SNAPSHOT artifacts and play around with them without intending to ever put them productive (in the preliminary state they are in).

Having said all that: You *can* deploy to different Maven repositories depending on Maven profiles. You just need to put the `<distributionManagement>` into a profile and activate/deactivate it on the command line (or some other profile activation mechanism). You just need to be sure you really need this.

Comment: Thanks JF Meier. totally makes scene what you said about not rebuilding artifacts. The thing is we still have to do ppe and prod build for other things and for compliance reasons. But we can skip building maven artifacts and instead, we can move/tag the particular version of artifacts to next stage. What is the normal process of moving/tagging artifacts? Is there a doc/example that you can point it to me? And another question with move/tag process is: how can we handle hot fixes? means what if something is checked in into release branch directly? how the process would look like?

Comment: We are also lacking good tool support for this. You can use tagging/properties features of your Nexus 3 or Artifactory, if you have one. You can also move the artifacts between (sub-)repositories of your Maven repositories. Some repositories (like Nexus 2) also have a staging mechanism (I don't recommend the one of Nexus 2). I would advise to move hot fixes through the stages as well, but with increased velocity.